# Standard groups and users on RHEL 7 base

Tags: users, groups, rhel7

Could anyone provide me with a list of the default groups and users which ship with RHEL 7.x base installation?

Comment: It takes about 10 minutes to spin up a small VM with a base install and see the list for yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

GROUPS

root
bin
daemon
sys
adm
tty
disk
lp
mem
kmem
wheel
cdrom
mail
man
dialout
floppy
games
tape
video
ftp
lock
audio
nobody
users
utmp
utempter
input
systemd-journal
systemd-bus-proxy
systemd-network
dbus
polkitd
ssh_keys
dip
tss
sshd
postdrop
postfix

USERS

root
bin
daemon
adm
lp
sync
shutdown
halt
mail
operator
games
ftp
nobody
systemd-bus-proxy
systemd-network
dbus
polkitd
tss
sshd
postfix